# Having trouble making ships appear on the command prompt!

Tags: c

I building a battleship game in C. I have the following code to validate that the points of the randomly placed ship don't exceed the board limit. The code doesn't work very smoothly and the application hangs while generating the random points.

Could you recommend some optimizations to what I have?

```
while(1 == 1)
  {  
      //Generates the x, y coordenates of the point
      int x = rand() % 9;
      int y = rand() % 9;      

      //Calculating the ship direction
      char direction = ((rand() % 10) > 5) ? 'V' : 'H';   

      if(direction == 'H')
      {
           //Verifies that the ship placed on the acquired x coordenate of the point does not exceed the board size
           //if so recalculates the value of x               
           while(!(((x + ships[i].length) - 1) < 10)) x = (rand() % 5);
      }
      else
      {
           //Verifies that the ship placed on the acquired y coordenate of the point does not exceed the board size
           //if so recalculates the value of y
           while(!(((y + ships[i].length) - 1) < 10)) y = (rand() % 5);
      }                              

      //Calculating the coordenates for each point of the ship                             
      for(j = 0; j < ships[i].length; j++)
      {
          if(direction == 'H')
          {                                      
             points[j].x = (x + j);
             points[j].y = y;
          }    
          else
          {
             points[j].x = x;
             points[j].y = (y + j);                                                        
          }

          //Validating that the coordenate asigned to a point has not been assigned to another ship              
          if(verifyPos(points[j].x, points[j].y, ships, length)) 
          {           
              invalid = 1;
              break;
          }
      }

      //if all the points of the ship are valid, move to the next ship
      //if not recalculate the initial point and the subsequent coordenates
      if(invalid == 0) break;       
  }

  ships[i].points = points;
 }   
}
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. The correct thing to do in this situation is to edit your old (closed) question and try to get it reopened.

Comment: I'm new here, and I didnt know how to make my older post reopened. So I decide to try again explaining my question.

Comment: That's OK - but you might want to read [this question on the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) to better understand the process.

Comment: Can you give some specific examples/scenarios and describe what "it doesn't work" means?

Comment: Your question is "too generic". Unfortunately this means that if we answered it all we would effectively finish your homework for you (and we don't want to spoil all the fun).

Comment: if the random coordenates are [4,0] [5,0] [6,0] [7,0]  and [7,0] [7,1] [7,2] maybe will appear the third ship or will not appear anything. Other ex: if the lenght of the ship is 3 and the first coordenate is [9,4] that whip is not going to appear oon the board.

Comment: what i want is make the program look for another coordinate if the one it found cant be used.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code _does_ choose new, random coordinates when the coordinates it originally chose cause ships to collide - or at least, that's what the code tries to do. Can you show us the code for `verifyPos()` and the loop(s) that lie outside the `while` loop? It could be that you are making a mistake with the `points` array somewhere.

Comment: Hi, I made some changes to my question in order to explain better the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed the randomizer.

```
#include <time.h>

srand(time(NULL));
```

is a trivial way to do it.

Comment: so tell me, how you called `srand()` before? Can you paste the exact line?

Comment: it is important that the `srand()` is OUTSIDE the while loop and be called only once. `rand()` is a pseudo number generator, meaning that it will give you the same results everytime you seed it with the same number.

Comment: I have it the same way you mention!!:(

Comment: @hexa My interpretation of her problem is that she's saying the randomly generated ship positions are the same between *two ships*. The problem isn't that when she runs the program, the first ship goes in the same spot (IMHO). The `while` loop only checks that the position for a single ship fits within the board, but not that it doesn't overlap another already-existing ship. My guess is that this is basically a random Battleship game generator type thing, and you can't have overlapping ships. In that case, she'll need to change her `while()` loop to check for additional constraints.

Comment: The problem is that the second invocation to the rand() function hangs. Its like it always generates the same number regardless of the seed.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way of improving it would be to choose which direction the ship is going to go V or H and then only use the section of the board that it will fit into so if the ship is 4 long and verticle only use rows 1-7 (of a 10 row board) for the verticle starting point. THen you don't need to check if it will fit at all.

Looking at the code, I don't see where the points assigned in

```
points[j].x = x;
points[j].y = (y + j);
```

are cleared if a ship is invalid. As far as I can see teh points array may be filling up with invalid points.